# Angular error - Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular

After upgrading from Angular version 8 to 10.

Running the - ng serve command gives me error -

ERROR in node_modules/ngx-tree-select/src/module.d.ts:11:56 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s).

11     static forRoot(options: TreeSelectDefaultOptions): ModuleWithProviders;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This is my file - fronent/webapp/node_modules/ngx-tree-select/src/module.d.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeSelectDefaultOptions } from './models/tree-select-default-options';
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
import * as ɵngcc1 from './components/tree-select.component';
import * as ɵngcc2 from './components/tree-select-item.component';
import * as ɵngcc3 from './directives/off-click.directive';
import * as ɵngcc4 from './pipes/item.pipe';
import * as ɵngcc5 from '@angular/common';
import * as ɵngcc6 from '@angular/forms';
export declare class NgxTreeSelectModule {
    static forRoot(options: TreeSelectDefaultOptions): ModuleWithProviders;
    static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta<NgxTreeSelectModule, [typeof ɵngcc1.TreeSelectComponent, typeof ɵngcc2.TreeSelectItemComponent, typeof ɵngcc3.OffClickDirective, typeof ɵngcc4.ItemPipe], [typeof ɵngcc5.CommonModule, typeof ɵngcc6.FormsModule], [typeof ɵngcc1.TreeSelectComponent]>;
    static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDef<NgxTreeSelectModule>;
}

//# sourceMappingURL=module.d.ts.map
```

Kindly view the image for the error.

[image]

Comment: have you solved the issue? facing the same issue after upgrading from 9 to 10

Comment: I haven't got any solution on this issue. Whenever I run ng server I get lot of errors related to ngx-tree-select @MuhmmadAbubakarIkram

Comment: I got to know that ngx-bootstrap is not compatible with angular 10 right now, 6.0.0 version of ngx-bootstrap will be compatible with angular 10 see this thread for more details on the issue, I resolved the issue so far using suggestion provided in this comment on github https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5831#issuecomment-653481625

Answer (score 58):

@user9882419 has the best approach i believe. Here is an example to illustrate what he is saying

```
export class AppSharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AppSharedModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: AppSharedModule
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: this is for one's own code; @Dmitri's approach will work when the problem is in a library

Answer (score 34):

To skip this type error just add in you code:

```
declare module "@angular/core" {
    interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
        ngModule: Type<T>;
        providers?: Provider[];
    }
}
```

Note: this will fix the type checking and allow to continue - if you will notice other lib to Angular10 inconmpatibilities - you need to ask lib upgrade or found another one.

Comment: where to add above piece of code in angular application

Comment: simpler and more direct is to simply provide the type, for example

Comment: @ankitkothari - you need to load it before your outdated library was loaded, say in the polifills.ts. I have for that purpose helper.types.d.ts file where I keep such stuff.

Comment: @ckapilla - my fix is for 3rd party libs where you can not and want not to make a fix.

Comment: @Dmitry -- oh I see -- it had happened in my own code so I was thinking in that context

Comment: This worked for me. @Dmitry can you please elaborate on why this works also a little more light on why this error crops up? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisOdney The one of the breaking changes in Angular10 - this interface sygnature changed from
interface ModuleWithProviders{} to interface ModuleWithProviders<T> {}

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/goldens/public-api/core/core.d.ts#L564

my fix is make it compartible, ie I define a default value for T as ANY.

Comment: Thank you - confirmed that adding this block as the last entry to polyfills.ts, just under the "APPLICATION IMPORTS" comment, works perfectly

Comment: This works but when I try to deploy my application the error appears once more, is there a fix for this?

Comment: This is good for a consumer utilizing an outdated library.  If you are a library developer, please provide the module type.

Comment: I added the code snippet to the bottom of my pollyfill.ts, but got the error ``` Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'providers' must be of type '(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[]', but here has type 'Provider[]'.ts(2717)
```

Comment: @Tarek Eldeeb - this snippet was correct for Angular 10, in your case you need to use type `(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[]`  instead of `Provider[]`.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 21):

add this code in your `tsconfig.app.json`
`"skipLibCheck": true,`

[image]

Comment: this will mute the current warning or error, but what if the library is outdated and there is new update, and what cli is actually trying to say: update me.

Answer (score 17):

The solve for the same error in my Angular 10.1.3 version, was change the param of export to .

With error:

```
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

After change:

```
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 10):

You just need to specify the type (the name of the module class) between ModuleWithProviders

Answer (score 2):

One cause of this is upgrading Angular to a newer version (i.e. v10), yet having an older JS library that doesn't play nice and also needs to be updated. In my case I received the following error like the OP:

> ERROR in [at-loader]
> ./node_modules/**@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap**/popover/popover.module.d.ts:6:23
> TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s).

Notice in my instance the particular offending library was called out which was `@ng-bootstrap` It indeed was on a much older version:

`"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0"`

I was able to update the package to version `7.0.0` and the error went away and the application built successfully. The main solution here is don't immediately throw in the fixes recommended here or use `<any>` in place of a type. There might just be another package you need to update to bring you app compliant with the version of Angular being used to fix the issue correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing issues in toastr.module.ts

Before:-

```
export declare class ToastrModule {
    static forRoot(config?: Partial<GlobalConfig>): ModuleWithProviders;
}
export declare class ToastrComponentlessModule {
    static forRoot(config?: Partial<GlobalConfig>): ModuleWithProviders;
}
```

After:-

```
export declare class ToastrModule {
    static forRoot(config?: Partial<GlobalConfig>): ModuleWithProviders<any>;
}
export declare class ToastrComponentlessModule {
    static forRoot(config?: Partial<GlobalConfig>): ModuleWithProviders<any>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this [ngx-tree-select](https://github.com/Crazyht/ngx-tree-select) library has not evolved with latest Angular versions. Maybe you should open a PR request or an issue on the repo.

Comment: Yes you are right @Thierry Falvo the PR request is raised - https://github.com/Crazyht/ngx-tree-select/issues/193

Answer (score 1):

Just provide "unknown" as Type-Argument.
I had the same issue and I solved it as in the following snippet

```
export const routingModule: ModuleWithProviders<unknown> = RouterModule.forRoot(
  routes
);
```

Comment: may I know where can I add this?

Answer (score 1):

since you got error in node modules you have limited scope to fix. So please try to get the latest compatible version with the angular(your version).

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of errors.  I had to go through them one by one and update the packages to later versions where the publishers had already fixed this.  Look at the file name and it'll give you a clue what package needs to be updated.  At least one of the packages didn't have a current update and had a massive backlog of issues and pull requests.  I don't know what I'm going to do about that one.  I might either have to replace that package with something else or use one of the solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

The error is mostly due to npm module (which ever is mentioned in the error) version is incompatible with the angular version which you want to migrate ( or version in your local machine).
Check the compatible version in https://www.npmjs.com/package/<package_name>