# Angular 10 error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>

Tags: angular, flatpickr

I have upgraded to Angular 10 and I am getting the following error:

```
  ERROR in node_modules/angularx-flatpickr/flatpickr.module.d.ts:6:64 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

6     static forRoot(userDefaults?: FlatpickrDefaultsInterface): ModuleWithProviders;
```

Comment: Try this trick from my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62988875/2838615

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some Angular libraries, such as @angular/router and @ngrx/store, implement APIs that return a type called ModuleWithProviders (typically via a method named forRoot()). This type represents an NgModule along with additional providers. Angular version 9 deprecates use of ModuleWithProviders without an explicitly generic type, where the generic type refers to the type of the NgModule.

read the full documentation here (https://next.angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers)

open Flatpickr.module.d.ts

and you can put **unknown** if you don't know the type

```
  export declare class FlatpickrModule {
   static forRoot(userDefaults?: FlatpickrDefaultsInterface): ModuleWithProviders<unknown>;
   }
```