# error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular10

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.module.d.ts:7:74 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    
    7     static enablePersistence(persistenceSettings?: PersistenceSettings): ModuleWithProviders;
```

I am getting the above error on adding firebase to my Angular 10 project. (no issues with old angular 9 project)

**Steps I took to add firebase**

1. *npm install firebase @angular/fire --save*
2. *ng add @angular/fire*
3. updated **environment.ts**

```
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: <secret> ,
    authDomain: <secret>,
    databaseURL: <secret>,
    projectId: <secret>,
    storageBucket: <secret>,
    messagingSenderId: <secret>,
    appId: <secret>,
    measurementId: <secret>
  }
};
```

4. Updated **app.module.ts**

```
// Firebase imports
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    QuicklinkModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    SharedModule,

    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), // Main Angular fire module
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> [ModuleWithProviders Migration Angular.io documentation](https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers)

Comment: > Project Info

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "firebase": "^7.18.0",
    "ngx-quicklink": "^0.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: is this thread of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755093/angular-error-generic-type-modulewithproviderst-requires-1-type-arguments

Comment: @MariaK. above thread is also of the same error code, but not helpful.

Comment: it also contains a link to the discussion of 3rd party integrations

Comment: @MariaK. thank you, found the workaround from the thread you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I have the latest version of angular and got the same issue, just added this line :

```
 "skipLibCheck": true;
```

to **tconfig.app.json**

```
    {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the firestore library. It just got fixed:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/commit/93912bc3e9e41d48628a8671c766b0c2e8b65dc8

Try updating your dependencies to the latest version. That should fix things.

Comment: yes I am using the latest version of firebase( firestore)

Comment: `static enablePersistence(persistenceSettings?: PersistenceSettings): ModuleWithProviders<AngularFirestoreModule> ` is present in my local version of  
 **firestore.module.ts **

Comment: on adding  "skipLibCheck": true to tsconfig.app.json solved the issue , but  is it correct thing to do ?

Comment: now I have commented the `"skipLibCheck": true` and it works.

Comment: @RamitDour It's not a good idea. The problem is that they fixed the issue in their module.ts file, but the bug is still l there in there in your module.d.ts, which is generating the error. The flag you set tells the compiler to forget about checking those files in your project. If you do that, you'll lost some type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround from [GitHub issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5831)

**working** : update **tsconfig.app.json**

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

> append "skipLibCheck": true

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in another answer, this issue has already been fixed: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/commit/93912bc3e9e41d48628a8671c766b0c2e8b65dc8

But it's not included in the latest ***stable*** release of @angular/fire (version 6.0.2 which was released late june) which you are using. However, there is a fix version available which is not a stable release but fixed. If you change your version of @angular/fire to 6.0.3-canary.93912bc it will work with the latest Angular 10 build.