# error after updating Angular cli from 8 to 10

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v9

I have upgraded my Angular project from 8 to 10 but while compiling I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-loading/lib/ngx-loading.module.d.ts:4:55 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

4     static forRoot(loadingConfig: INgxLoadingConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/export/export.component.ts:83:24 - error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import("jspdf")' has no construct signatures.

83     const pdfDoc = new jsPDF('l');
```

I am not able to find out what is happening here.

can anyone please help me with this?

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: as stated on the github repo of ngx-loading repo, it doesn't support Angular 9/10. About the second issue, you need to add typing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular error - Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755093/angular-error-generic-type-modulewithproviderst-requires-1-type-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Angular 9 `ModuleWithProviders` needs generic type that refers to the type of the `NgModule`.

https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers

The ngx-loading project doesn't implement these changes, yet. But as it seems [there is a pull request](https://github.com/Zak-C/ngx-loading/pull/114) waiting to be done.