# ng-multiselect-dropdown not working properly in Angular10 throws following error

Tags: angular10

ERROR in node_modules/ng-multiselect-dropdown/ng-multiselect-dropdown.module.d.ts:3:23 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s).

```
3     static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular error - Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755093/angular-error-generic-type-modulewithproviderst-requires-1-type-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

In your polyfills.ts file just add:

```
declare module "@angular/core" {
    interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
        ngModule: Type<T>;
        providers?: Provider[];
    }
}
```

If you follow the link given from @thefolenangel, you can see it is already answered.