# How to install ng4-loading-spinner

Tags: angular

I have tried to install [ng4-loading-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-loading-spinner) but it shows

> ERROR in node_modules/ng4-loading-spinner/index.d.ts:5:23 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s). 5 static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders;

Comment: Possibly related: [Angular error - Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755093/angular-error-generic-type-modulewithproviderst-requires-1-type-arguments)

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using and which version of ng4-loading-spinner are you trying to import?

Comment: Angular version:10.0.8,ng4 version: 1.2.3

Comment: Have red it's documentation max support is up to angular 7, may be you can clone the source and upgrade it first then you can use it.